# Reset first select list when second is active...(select2 plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to reset the first list when second is active and reset second list when first list is active(to return to *Choose an option...*)...I use select2 Jquery plugin. I tried with the code

```
$('#second').change(function(){
    $('#first').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});

$('#first').change(function(){
    $('#second').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

but it does not work. Code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godfather/M586F/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select2` overload's `val` method to pass-in the first options value (if it has) to reset it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKfyG/)

```
$('#second').change(function(){
    $('#first').select2('val','');
});
$('#first').change(function(){
    $('#second').select2('val','');
});
```

See **[Doc](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation)**

> val :
> Gets or sets the selection. If the value parameter is not specified, the id attribute of the currently selected element is returned. If the value parameter is specified it will become the current selection.